ZAP Error : Connection refused (Connection refused)
I am running the zap proxy in dockerfile using the below command on my windows machine:
FROM softwaresecurityproject/zap-bare

ENV API_DISABLEKEY=true
ENV ZAP_AUTO_UPDATE=false
ENV ZAP_PORT=9090

EXPOSE 9090

CMD ["zap.sh", "-daemon", "-port", "9090", "-config", "api.disablekey=true", "-config", "api.addrs.addr.name=.*", "-config", "api.addrs.addr.regex=true", "-config", "view.mode=attack", "-host", "0.0.0.0", "-config", "network.localServers.mainProxy.behindNat=true", "-config", "network.connection.timeOutInSecs=120", "-config", "network.httpState.timeoutInSecs=120", "-silent"]

and i build and run this dockerfile using these commands:
docker build -t custom-zap .   
docker run -p 8080:9090 --name custom-zap custom-zap

Sadly i get this error when i open the http://localhost:8080/ on my browser:
ZAP Error [org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException]: Connect to http://localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

I noticed the zap proxy is running in container correctly, however i think as i get the below log too:
2024-05-24 08:14:04 4368 [ZAP-daemon] INFO  org.zaproxy.addon.callhome.ExtensionCallHome - Shh! Silent mode or telemetry turned off
2024-05-24 08:14:04 4376 [ZAP-daemon] INFO  org.zaproxy.addon.network.ExtensionNetwork - ZAP is now listening on 0.0.0.0:9090


You appear to have connected to ZAP but ZAP is then trying to connect to localhost:8080 and nothing is listenning on that port in the container.
We recommend that you use the IP address of the docker container, not localhost. You can find this using docker inspect.
More details on https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/about/#accessing-the-api-from-outside-of-the-docker-container
